# What is the most efficient way to remove old / unused views and stored procedures from a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, view

I was given the task of archiving (renaming "example" to "example_archived") and deleting unused views and stored procedures in our database.

The database is cluttered with objects named like:

- "PurchaseAnalysis_v1",
- "PurchaseAnalysis_v2",
- "PurchaseAnalysis_v3",
- "PurchaseAnalysis_v1_test3",
- "PurchaseAnalysis_v1_test5",
  and so on.

In most cases, we do not know which objects are in active use but we do need to clean up the mess.

What would be the most optimal way (if any) to find and remove the unneccessary views and stored procedures?

I have tried to view dependencies in SSMS but that gave me practically no further information.

Comment: This sounds like what you really need is better source control/deployment processes; deploying many versions like that is a nightmare to work with (take it from someone that experienced it). Get your database into source control and then you have built in version control there and can easily roll back if/when you need to.

Comment: It depends on your stack. I would say, if you don't know, you shouldn't do it because you don't have good enough control of your code

Comment: Most effecient would be to change names of everything and see what crashes, but if that's the best way...

Comment: It could be used dynamically, or directly from an ad-hoc batch in the application. You need to look at your application code.

Comment: For pure sql code, you can check all databases for your procedure names under the sys.sql_modules - definition column and see where it's referenced. msdb..sysjobsteps contains command which has procedure name for sql agent jobs. For rest of your stack, you can use file search i guess. The search won't be perfect, because some things are built dynamically, but it's a start